# Who was first to prove the Boltzman H-theorem for the Landau kinetic equation?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Who has proved [Boltzmann's H-theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-theorem) (which tells that entropy of a closed system grows as the system approaches thermal equilibrium) for the kinetic equation with Landau collisions operator? One proof is provided by F. Hinton in 1st volume of "Basis plasma physic" (edited by Sudan and Galeev) but I wonder if Hinton was the first.